# QtCreator error; can't load library; ProjectExplorer(2.6.82)

Tags: 12.10, ubuntu-touch, ubuntu-sdk

I try to install the new Ubuntu Phone SDK using the instructions here:
http://developer.ubuntu.com/resources/app-developer-cookbook/mobile/currency-converter-phone-app/

Unfortunately when I run Qt-Creator it says a bunch of plugins failed to load:

```
Cannot load plugin because dependency failed to load: ProjectExplorer(2.6.82)
Reason: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/qtcreator/plugins/QtProject/libProjectExplorer.so: Cannot load library /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/qtcreator/plugins/QtProject/libProjectExplorer.so: (libQt5Declarative.so.5: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory)
```

Is there a missing step in the instructions, is something wrong with my setup, or is this not yet working in 12.10?

Comment: libqt5declarative5 is install correct ?

Comment: That was it, thanks! Hopefully the final Ubuntu Phone SDK will have updated dependency info so that doesn't happen.

Answer (score 4):

Run:

```
sudo apt-get install libbotan*
```

Answer (score 1):

Had the same problem. The error message also contains the answer. There is a missing `libbotan*.so`. So it is a missing dependency problem in the `qtcreator` package.

```
sudo apt-get install libbotan-1.10-0
```